# LSI MegaRAID X99 / Haswell-E

Tags: raid, chipset, haswell

Does anyone know if [LSI MegaRAID cards](http://www.lsi.com/products/raid-controllers/pages/default.aspx) will work with the new [X99 chipset](http://wccftech.com/intel-haswelle-x99-chipset-wellsburg-details-leaked-ddr4/)?

I've seen some reports of people using CPUs / Chipsets not on LSI's compatibility matrix, but that information is hard to find and I don't know if it can be trusted.

These cards seem to support some X79 systems, and I'm guessing X99 is based on X79...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only boards that I have found that officially support LSI MegaRAID cards are some of the ASUS boards. Although LSI has not yet officially declared them compatible, ASUS has in their Device QVL lists on their website.

[ASUS X99-Deluxe Device QVL](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA2011/X99-DELUXE/X99-S-DELUXE_Devices_Report.pdf)

[ASUS X99 X99-E WS Device QVL](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/server/X99-E_WS/QVL/X99_E_WS_Device_QVL_140902.pdf)

Comment: Good find! +1, I see they only listed 3 of the internal connecter cards. Probably all they had to test with. That's an amazing mobo, with price to match...